# How to find invisible srt file?

Tags: windows, video, file-management, file-search, mkv

Just downloaded a movie and when I went to watch movie (foreign language) i turned on the subtitles however noticed there was no .srt subtitle file or any other file back in the folder in which the movie is. 
I have to find the actual srt subtitle file to change its name to name of movie so i can watch it on tv because tv doesnt read subtitles unless they are same name as the movie. i literally looked everywhere on the pc for any srt file and found nothing. When i go to turn on the subtitle in the video playing software it is ther e called "en" and it works when turned on however i cannot find it anywhere on the computer so i can rename the file.
Any help thanks.
please any help thank you!
in the bottom left corner where the subtitle file option is it just appears as 1.en however any attempt to find this doesnt turn up anything
i just need to find where the subtitle file is or just how to rename it

Comment: hello mawg could you please answer my question if you are going to down vote it thank you very much.

Comment: this site is not here to support software or computer questions is here to provide software alternatives to a set of defined requirements. Your question is regarding a TV and how it reads the internal subtitle streams of what it seems to be a matroska file. This has nothing to do with software RECOMMENDATIONS. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

even if this is not the right board for this kind of question (you posted in "software recommendations") I'm gonna try my best to answer it.

I'm not entirely sure if I understood your problem, but as far as I got it you have the following situation:
You downloaded a video file (for example a .mp4 file) and in your video player you can turn on the subtitles but you need the .srt file seperately for your TV. Now many video formats (like mp4) support to embed the subtitles directly in the file, without any separate .srt file. I guess this is also the case with your video. So if you need an extra srt file for your TV you can export it using a tool like [Subtitle Edit](https://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit). Just open the video file with the program and save the .srt where you want it.

I hope I was able to help you!